# Java Create JDBCTemplate Singleton Bean without Writing DataSource

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I am attempting to make JdbcTemplate a Singleton Bean, instead of having it called in multiple repositories .

In the current code base, I didn't need to even write DataSource config.

For my new code singleton Config Bean attempt, is there a way to set the JDBCTemplate, without going through DataSource config?

**Current Code:**

```
@Repository
public class CustomerRepositoryImpl implements CustomerRepository {

    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public CustomerRepositoryImpl(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate) {
        this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate = namedParameterJdbcTemplate;
    }

}
```

it would automatically read the DataSource using application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;encrypt=true;databaseName=Test
spring.datasource.username= sauser
spring.datasource.password= sauserpw
```

**New Code Attempt:**

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource)
    {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
}

// trying to prevent writing this code in for Datasource if possible, and importing a new maven package com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource;

SQLServerDataSource dataSource = new SQLServerDataSource();
dataSource.setUser("sauser");
dataSource.setPassword("sauserpw");
dataSource.setServerName("localhost");
dataSource.setDatabaseName("Test");


@Repository
public class CustomerRepositoryImpl implements CustomerRepository {

    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public CustomerRepositoryImpl(DatabaseConfig databaseConfig) {
        this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate = databaseConfig.namedParameterJdbcTemplate();
```

Note: There is no error, trying to reduce the code base and simplify it

Comment: try to import  ```spring-boot-autoconfigure``` package which would have the abality to autowired datasource config into spring . so that you can use JdbcTemplate  with that  annotation ```Auotwired``` above

Comment: hi @Peng feel free to write as answer, and I can send points, sorry on vacation, dont have access to IDE, thanks

Comment: got it , it 's ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use JdbcTemplate and inject it as a bean and spring will automatically handle everything. Since in your case you only need to connect with single data source, mention the mandatory dependencies and relevant properties, declaring JdbcTemplate as bean will solve all your problems.

```
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
 import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
 import javax.sql.DataSource;

 @Configuration
 public class JdbcTemplateConfig {

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
       return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
 }
```

this would be your JdbcConfig.
Note : you don't need JdbcConfig class, you can initialize JdbcTemplate bean directly in your application's config.

Include `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency in your project.

You can use this bean in your repository in the following way.

```
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
   import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

   @Repository
   public class YourRepository {

   private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

   @Autowired
   public YourRepository(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
      this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
   }

   public String fetchData() {

    String sql = "SELECT your_column FROM your_table WHERE some_condition";
    return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, String.class);
   }
}
```

Hope this resolves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

try to import `spring-boot-autoconfigure` package which would have the abality to autowired datasource config into spring . so that you can use `JdbcTemplate` with that annotation Auotwired above

Answer (score -1):

Why are you trying to create the `DatabaseConfig` at all? I don't have the source code at hand, but your current code is working, you get a jdbc-Template injected which is created by autocobfiguration (as a singleton).

AutoConfiguration is implemented in a way, that it backs off when certain conditions are met, in order to not interfere with manual configuration.

It is quite possible, that by creating the jdbctemplate by yourself, that the datasource configuration backs off.

You can check this by starting spring boot in debug mode. You can see there which autoconfigurations are choosen and which are omitted and why.

If you still want to create your own jdbctemplate you can create the datasource just like spring boot does. In those case I take a look a the corresponding spring boot source. E.g. the Database properties are loaded in the `DatabaseProperties` bean...

BTW. your new Repository code is unnecessary complicated. If you have a Configuration class, that creates a bean, then it is a singleton by default. If you autowire that bean, you get the singleton injected. Injecting the configuration class and calling the bean method makes it unnecessary complicated. I would recommend you to use a debugger and check the object ids during execution to see how it works.

Answer (score -1):

Of course you may enable Autoconfiguration, but it doesn't change the fact that somehow you must let Spring know database parameters. Strictly speaking, you have already used it, because pointing out values in the `application.properties` without explicit assigning in the Java code is precisely an example of the Autoconfiguration.

Given this, the question is what exactly the goal? To get rid of configuration within the project? If so, I recommend you to take a look at the [Spring Cloud Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/) which provides numerous ways of configuration out of the project, such as git, vault, DB, etc.
Another way is to omit database configuration parameters in the config file and pass them as environmental variables. The thing is that each configuration parameter may be described as an environment variable, following a simple naming convention: period-separated config parameter will be overriden by the environment variable with the same name. Periods becomes underscores, dashes will be omited.

```
server.port -> SERVER_PORT
my.new-param -> MY_NEWPARAM
```

There is a section about [externalizing of the configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config) in the Spring reference. And keep in mind the priority of java/env/file configurations if mix them.

And again: it's not a magic, you can't just remove configuration of the datasource - it's an abstraction that lets your service know how to connect to the database. But you can keep and manage this configuration separately from the project.